# Large meshing with tetgen

Tags: python, mesh-generation, unstructured-mesh

So I have a point cloud that I am creating a 3D flat rectangular surface from.  I'm then turning it into a hollow box and connecting the corners by just dropping this surface mesh down.  I need it to be consistently a meter thick throughout so it is important to drop the surface mesh down so it matches the 1 meter delta z from the top.  So I end up with something that looks like this: [image: surface mesh dropped for time with side connectivites]

The problem is that tetgen even when I'm allowing it to doesn't want to seem to throw away points.  So I would like a very refined mesh at top and a coarse one at the bottom.  It wants to keep all of the bottom points, so if I drop the mesh one time 1 meter down and give it a high volume constraint I get something like this: 
[image]

As you can see it is refined at the top but it needs to go back to being refined at the bottom to match the surface mesh.  I don't want tetgen to keep these facets.  I'm wanting it to get coarser as it goes down.  Does anyone know how to fix this problem?  Or maybe some other software that is better suited to my needs?  Thanks for your help and for taking a look.  I'm most proficient in python, so I have used meshpy in the past as well.

Comment: welcome to StackExchange! I think your question is best asked on the tetgen forums and mailing lists as this is where the people who know the software best hang out.

Comment: You are most likely right, although I had a lot of trouble locating any tetgen mailing list.  So, I figured that the computational section would be more appropriate than stackoverflow.  Thanks for the welcome!